# Getting ORA-00904 invalid identifier error, but the identifier has been created

Tags: sql, oracle, identifier

I'm having trouble with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE Department (
  Department_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  Department_Name CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  Department_Location CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
  Department_Phone_Number INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_Employee
  FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID)
  REFERENCES Employee(Employee_ID)
);
```

I am getting an `ORA-00904: "EMPLOYEE_ID": invalid identifier` error, but I already created an employee table with the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  Employee_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  Employee_Name CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  Date_Of_Birth DATE NOT NULL,
  Job_Title CHAR (15) NOT NULL,
  Marriage_Date DATE NULL,
  Spouse_Name CHAR(25) NULL
);
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have Employee_id column, on which you define the foreign key in your Department table as well:

```
CREATE TABLE Department
(Department_ID integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Department_Name CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Department_Location CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
Department_Phone_Number integer NOT NULL,
Employee_ID integer null,
CONSTRAINT fk_Employee
FOREIGN KEY (Employee_ID)
REFERENCES Employee(Employee_ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I see there is no EMPLOYEE_ID column In dedepartment table. Create a column first in department table and then reference foreign key for the employee table